# Quit application, update data, and open again, in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

How can I close my application on nodejs, and then reopen?

Can I do with SPAWN (child_process)?

I need to close the application, perform the update on the data, and then open the application again.

I'm not sure how I can open the application after it has been closed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [respawn](https://github.com/mafintosh/respawn) will help. Pay attention to the graceful restart at the bottom of the link

Comment: I tried using respaw, I configured the node to run my application (app.js)
const monitor = respawn(['node', 'app.js'], {....

however, I get the following error:
Error: Cannot find module '/home/updateTeste/node'


App.js is in the root folder.
It looks like you are creating a new directory with the first parameter of the respawn configuration.